# Adding a Math.ceil

Tags: jquery, math, input, calculator

Background: I have a jquery calculator that works out the total cost and number of cans/tins/pots needed based on the user input of width and height of the area needed painted.

It works but I need the number of cans to round-up, i.e. Math.celi so it reflects the minimum amount of cans needed to paint the desired area surface.  On top of that, I need to multiply the round-up whole figure by the cost per can of £18.23 to reflect what the minimum cans needed will cost.

How do I add a Math.celi to the below line in my code? I'm just a novice and blindly trying to add iT in, guessing the syntax but ultimately failing.

```
$('#cans').html(canCount.toFixed(2));
```

I also need the cost value of £18.23 to * this rounded-up value (canCount) as an exact number: e.g. if canCount was 0.63 the Math.celi would make it 1 and * #cost (£18.23) the Total would be £18.23?

all associated code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/518/

Comment: I'm sorry, I read your question 5 times and I don't understand what you are asking. My suggestion: First rename your variables so that they describe what they hold. `firstValue`, `secondValue` etc. are completely useless names. Then describe what your code in general does. Is it working correctly? Then describe based on that what you want to change.

Comment: All done, and thanks - you're right of course...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line in your Fiddle from

```
$('#cans').html(canCount.toFixed(2));
```

To

```
$('#cans').html(Math.ceil(canCount.toFixed(2)));
```

Comment: thats great! I think my problem was spelling and omitting a ) anyway, how do I get the total to multiply by the whole (i.e. round-up) number?